# Getting error "ipfamily IPv6 is not configured on cluster" when applying kubectl apply service.yaml

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Using Kubernetes 1.21 which is dual stack and calico network but after applying service.yaml getting error "The Service "eva-ce-node-port-service-0" is invalid: spec.ipFamilies[0]: Invalid value: []string(nil): ipfamily IPv6 is not configured on cluster"

But pod is showing dual ip(ipv4 and ipv6)

To resolve the issue I added below lines in service.yaml:
ipFamilyPolicy: PreferDualStack
ipFamilies:

- IPv6
- IPv4
  but after adding those lines still getting the above mentioned error.

```
The Service "eva-ce-node-port-service-0" is invalid: spec.ipFamilies[0]: Invalid value: []string(nil): ipfamily IPv6 is not configured on cluster
```

Comment: can you share the fill yaml also for ref, if you are getting both IP as you mentioned `But pod is showing dual ip(ipv4 and ipv6)` what's the issue thn ?  https://medium.com/@elfakharany/how-to-enable-ipv6-on-kubernetes-aka-dual-stack-cluster-ac0fe294e4cf

Comment: here is the service.yaml file which I used:

Comment: here is the service.yaml file which I used: ```apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: eva-ce-node-port-service-0
  labels:
    component: eva-ce-node-port-service-0
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ipFamilyPolicy: PreferDualStack
  ports:```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you manage to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

The first test would be a [`kubectl cluster-info dump | grep -i family`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#interacting-with-nodes-and-cluster)

You need to check if IPv6 is actually activated on your cluster, or the `ipFamilyPolicy: PreferDualStack` won't matter.

If there is no ipV6 mention, then configure your CNI plugin.

For instance, [for Calico](https://docs.tigera.io/calico/latest/networking/ipam/ipv6) (`kubectl get configmap calico-config -n kube-system -o yaml`), you need to update its configuration with:

```
- name: CALICO_IPV6POOL_CIDR
  value: "<IPv6 subnet>"
- name: CALICO_IPV6POOL_BLOCK_SIZE
  value: "<IPv6 block size>"
```

The general idea remains: check ipV6 on your CNI first.

---

You can update the Calico CNI configuration by modifying the `calico-config` ConfigMap on the fly, without the need to redeploy the entire cluster (see [Install Calico with etcd datastore](https://docs.tigera.io/calico/latest/getting-started/kubernetes/self-managed-onprem/onpremises#install-calico-with-etcd-datastore)).
But you might have to restart the relevant pods (e.g., Calico components or the CNI plugin) for the changes to take effect. Deleting them should make Kubernetes restart them automatically.

The Calico CNI plugin creates an IP pool (with a default CIDR block of 192.168.0.0/16 for IPv4) if one isn't specified.

To add the IP pool configuration to the calico-config ConfigMap, you should place the configuration under the `data:` section, as that's where configuration information is stored.
The `metadata:` section is used for storing metadata about the ConfigMap, like its name and namespace, and is not the right place for configuration data.

Comment: Couple follow-up questions: (1) Can I update the configmap on the fly or do I need to redeploy the cluster? (2) I can't seem to find IPV4POOL in my calico configmap so unsure if there is other tricks to configure this thing or its normal to miss IPV4POOL and just defaulting? (3) Where should I put that config? under "data:" or "metadata:"